# Spinner Select item by object ID

Tags: android, android-spinner

How can I select programmatically one item in this spinner by the `idCat` of the `objectCategoria`? .

I've been trying `spinner.setSelection` but I can't select one item by the id of the object.

Thanks for helping.

```
final Spinner spinnerEs = (Spinner) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerCat);

final List<ObjectCategoria> adapCat = new TableControllerCategoria(this).read();

ArrayAdapter categ = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, adapCat);

spinnerEs.setAdapter(categ);
```

This spinner is filled with a list of these objects:

```
public class ObjectCategoria {
    int idCat;
    String categoria;

    public ObjectCategoria(){

    }

    public String getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public int getID(){
        return idCat;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return categoria;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can only use position, not id, sorry

Comment: You can take the position, get the id from that position then query that id from the list to get the object.